Declaration file not recognized as a module when bundled with --outFile
I'm trying to create type declarations for my TypeScript package, but I'm encountering an issue when bundling the declarations into a single file. Here's a simplified version of the setup:

I have a source file typedefs.ts:
export enum Action {
  filter,
  add,
}


Its contents are exported by index.ts:
export * from "./typedefs";


I generate the type declarations using tsc in bundled form, giving outFile:
$ npx tsc --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outFile dist/index.d.ts src/index.ts

This produces:
declare module "typedefs" {
    export enum Action {
        filter = 0,
        add = 1
    }
}
declare module "index" {
    export * from "typedefs";
}


When I attempt to import the package in another project, TypeScript is unable to load the typings and I get the error:
index.ts:1:40 - error TS2306: File '/tmp/baz/node_modules/foobar/dist/index.d.ts' is not a module.

1 import type { Action } from "foobar";
                                       ~~~~~~~~~


However, if I generate the declarations in non-bundled form, giving outDir, like so:
$ npx tsc --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist src/index.ts

Now TypeScript generates type declarations for each imported module without declare module clauses and importing the typings works as expected.


Why doesn't the "bundled" type declaration form work, while the non-bundled form does? How can I resolve this issue while still generating a single bundled type declaration file?
Both the exported and importing packages are declared as "type": "module". For the sake of simplicity and brevity, I used default TS settings but did experiment with various configurations, mostly focusing on target, module and moduleResolution.
